# Open and Close Syntastic window with one mapping

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin-syntastic

I have :SyntasticCheck mapped to F8 in my .vimrc.

```
map <F8> :SyntasticCheck<CR>
```

This open the Syntastic window on a split.

I would like to close it with the same mapping.
Closing is done with `:SyntasticReset`, but it only works if the Synastic window is open.

How can I create a mapping that only open Synastic windows if it's not visible and close it if it exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
function! ToggleSyntastic()
    for i in range(1, winnr('$'))
        let bnum = winbufnr(i)
        if getbufvar(bnum, '&buftype') == 'quickfix'
            lclose
            return
        endif
    endfor
    SyntasticCheck
endfunction

nnoremap <F8> :call ToggleSyntastic()<CR>
```

As Syntastic populates the location list, the function iterates through the different open windows. If it finds the quickfix window which contains the location list, then it closes it. If no quickfix window was found, then it runs `SyntasticCheck`

Then you can simply call <kbd>F8</kbd> to call the function.

Comment: Works flawlessly !

Comment: One liner if that is your bag: `nnoremap <expr> <f8> len(filter(range(1, winnr('$')), 'getbufvar(winbufnr(v:val), "&buftype") == "quickfix"')) ? ":\<c-u>lclose\<cr>" : ":\<c-u>SyntasticCheck\<cr>"`

Comment: @PeterRincker Personally I'd rather put the function in the `autoload` directory and have a readable code but one-liners can be nice too. Is there a significant performance gain when using `filter` rather than a full loop?

Comment: From what I understand, simple `filter()` & `map()` calls typically beat loops in Vimscript. However, I have not personally done any benchmarking. That being said, I think you are right maintainability is more important. That comes down to deciding if a more functional approach with `filter()` is more readable than a few lines in a loop. I know when I see `filter()`/`map()` that a loop is occurring under the covers, but I feel like this is very much a personal preference and whatever the project maintainer feels is the most appropriate. Performance-wise: the number of windows should be small